# Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):

Tags: angular

I have the following error:

./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleError: Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
/Users/pedrocovarrubias/Documents/GitHub/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/font-awesome/scss/_path.scss:6:2: Can't resolve '../node_modules/font-awesome/node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot' in '/Users/pedrocovarrubias/Documents/GitHub/Angular/conFusion/src'
at Object.emitError (/Users/pedrocovarrubias/Documents/GitHub/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:562:6)
at Declaration (/Users/pedrocovarrubias/Documents/GitHub/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/webpack/plugins/postcss-cli-resources.js:145:28)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async LazyResult.runAsync (/Users/pedrocovarrubias/Documents/GitHub/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:411:15)
at async Object.loader (/Users/pedrocovarrubias/Documents/GitHub/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:97:14)

Here is my style.scss code:

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
@import 'variables';
@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';

// some basic resets 

$lt-gray: #ddd;
$background-dark: #512DA8;
$background-light: #9575CD;
$background-pale: #D1C4E9;
$primary-color-dark:   #512DA8;
$primary-color:        #673AB7;
$primary-color-light:  #D1C4E9;
$primary-color-text:   #FFFFFF;
$accent-color:         #FFC107;
$primary-text-color:   #212121;
$secondary-text-color: #757575;
$divider-color:        #BDBDBD;

@mixin zero-margin($pad-up-down, $pad-left-right) {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: $pad-up-down $pad-left-right;
}

body { 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; 
}

.container {
    margin: 20px;
    display:flex;
}

.background-primary {
  background-color: $background-dark!important;
}
.background-accent {
  background-color: $accent-color!important;
}
.text-floral-white {
  color: floralwhite!important;
}

.flex-spacer {
flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Can someone help on this?

Comment: when you comment out everything in styles.scss does it fix the problem?

Comment: you using a recent version of Node.js? more recent versions of Angular only work with more recent versions of Node

Comment: when you comment out everything in styles.scss does it fix the problem? Yes, if I take out everything from styles.scss the problem is fix

Comment: OK, can you restore styles.scss slowly line by line and see which line is causing the problem? (restore half of it, then you know which half the problem is in, then the next quarter, etc)

Comment: you using a recent version of Node.js? more recent versions of Angular only work with more recent versions of Node Yes, I'm using node.js 14.x, as is the one that works with Angular 12.x

Comment: the one line that is causing the problem is:
@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';

Comment: ok, rather than import this in styles.scss you can import it via angular.json under the "styles" property. there are 2 "styles" properties in Angular.json, import it in both, that should fix it ... NOTE: if you take this approach you will need to restart your Angular dev server to pick up the changes

Comment: If you prefer to import from node_modules in styles.scss I think there is a special syntax using ~ ... something like @import "~swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index" .. I'm sure you can Google it if you prefer this approach

Comment: I added in the angular.json: "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome"
            ],
but the icons doesn't show in the webpage

Comment: dont use @import in angular.json, see my answer and make sure you restart Angular  dev server

Comment: I added in the angular.json like this: "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss", no problem to compile, but the icons doesn't show in the html, any suggestions?

Comment: do you need the .. ?

Comment: did you restart the angular dev server?

Comment: did you add this line for both styles properties in angular.json?

Comment: do you need the .. ? I take it out but no change

Comment: did you restart the angular dev server?  Yes

Comment: did you add this line for both styles properties in angular.json? Yes

Comment: OK when you restart your server, please do a hard reload on the browser ... to do a hard reload on Chrome, open devtools and then click on refresh and hold (devtools must be open) .. a menu will appear, select the hard reload option ... then check your network tab in devtools ... do you see an http request being made for the font-awesome icons? is it successful?

Answer (score 0):

To import from node_modules in styles.scss use the following syntax:

This line is importing from node_modules ... correct approach:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

This line is wrong it needs to use ~ syntax:

```
@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

Should probably be:

```
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

Or if that does not work import in angular.json like this:

```
"styles": [ "src/styles.scss", "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome" ]
```

Make sure to add to both "styles" properties in angular.json and to restart your dev server to pick up the changes. When importing from node_modules in this way make sure the file you are trying to import exists in your node_modules directory.

Comment: I added in the angular.json like this: "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss", no problem to compile, but the icons doesn't show in the html, any suggestions?

Comment: Ive just added 3 comments above - make sure you apply all 3 of my other comments which Ive just added

Comment: do you need the .. ? I take it out but no change
did you restart the angular dev server? Yes
did you add this line for both styles properties in angular.json? Yes

Comment: OK i added a new comment in main comment area above - please check that too thx

Comment: I fixed, I have to change to @import '~node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome' in styles.scss; also, in another file call _variables.scss, I have to change from $fa-font-path: '../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts'; to $fa-font-path: '~node_modules/font-awesome/fonts';

Comment: the more correct answer is ~ instead of .. since node_moudels is located in the root or home directory (your project folder). So ~ is for home, / for root and .. is for parent directory. In this case you could use ~ or / instead of .. .

Comment: great stuff glad its working, nice job

Answer (score 0):

For my error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Transform failed with 1 error:
error: Invalid version: "15.2-15.3"
```

I deleted mini-css-extract-plugin and @ngtool folders and ran `npm i`, and its working now.